# PDF Printing issues with embedded transparent CMYK image

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, pdf, images, transparency

I have a couple of PDF files here which are saved as PDF/X1a:2001. Those contain some outlined/curved text as well as an embedded background image.

In some of the PDFs there is a background picture which is tagged as "Transparent CMYK". Have a look at the attached image.

[image: Embedded image tags]

When printing those files on a large format printer (using a ripping software), I get awkward color results for all the files which contain a "Transparent CMYK" picture.

I tried Googling, Binging and DuckDuckGoing it, but I can not find any useful information about "Transparent CMYK".

Can you guys and girls help me out with some explaniation/links/sources that explain something about this?

Answer (score 1):

this may be some help, may not. Sometimes transparencies can really confuse rip software. In your psd file I would first try and flatten and save out as a high res jpg. - then use that file as your Ai embedded file. 
or rasterise the embedded file in illustrator. 
Failing that you'll have to flatten the transparencies